Why does this map operation on an ordered stream not preserve order?
The JavaDoc of stream package, says, "if the source of a stream is a List containing [1, 2, 3], then the result of executing map(x -> x*2) must be [2, 4, 6]. "
I have been trying to verify this behavior using the following code but the output doesn't match expectations.
Optional<String> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).parallel().map(i -> {
    try {
        if (i == 1) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return "" + i;
}).peek(x -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().threadId() + " Peeking " + x);
}).findFirst();

System.out.println(result);

The output is:
1 Peeking 3
23 Peeking 4
21 Peeking 2
22 Peeking 1
Optional[1]

Shouldn't the outgoing stream from the map operation have "1" first?
Also, even if I insert an unordered() operation before parallel, the result is still Optional1. Why? Shouldn't findFirst just return any value in that case instead of waiting for the operation for 1 to complete?
Only when I remove unordered() and parallel() operations, do I see the output as:
1 Peeking 1
Optional[1]

Meaning, findFirst() does short circuit. But why is it not short circuiting when the stream is unordered and parallel?
Based on @user2357112 comment I tried it by changing the peek operation to map as follows:
map(x -> {
    System.out.println("Remapping " + x);
    return "x"+x;
})

The output is still not in order:
Remapping 2
Remapping 4
Remapping 3
Remapping 1
Optional[x1]


"Shouldn't the outgoing stream from the map operation have "1" first?" - it does. That's why you got Optional[1] instead of Optional[3].

peeking a parallel stream does not respect order.

@user2357112 you are correct, the peek javadoc does say that. But I changed peek to map and the output is still not in order.

Printing output from multiple threads is not a way you can demonstrate a deterministic order, because printing from multiple threads in itself doesn't have a deterministic order. The only way you can demonstrate a deterministic order here is by printing the result of a terminal operation of the stream (e.g. a toList()).


The output is:
1 Peeking 3
23 Peeking 4
21 Peeking 2
22 Peeking 1
Optional[1]

Shouldn't the outgoing stream from the map operation have "1" first?

No.
You are asking for EXECUTION ORDER -- Kick off 1 first, then kick off 2 next, and so on.
No. Parallel streams by definition do NOT give you execution order. EVEN IF YOU PUT AN ordered() ON YOUR PARALLEL STREAM, YOU WILL NOT GET EXECUTION ORDER.
Putting an ordered() on your stream gives you RESULT ORDER. Meaning, your stream will order results ONCE THEY GET TO THE TERMINAL OPERATION. Not before then.

Also, even if I insert an unordered() operation before parallel, the result is still Optional[1]. Why? Shouldn't findFirst() just return any value in that case, instead of waiting for the operation for 1 to complete?

I tried this myself and I got Optional[3]. I am using an early access version of Java 23. Can you try running the below snippet for me, and see if you still get Optional[1] as your answer?
Optional<String> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).unordered().parallel().map(i -> {
    try {
        if (i == 1) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return "" + i;
}).peek(x -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().threadId() + " Peeking " + x);
}).findFirst();

If you get Optional[1], please also tell me your operating system, your version of Java, and the distributor (Oracle, Amazon, etc.).

Only when I remove unordered() and parallel() operations, do I see the output

So, you are doing Stream.of(). That is your source. And it has encounter order, meaning that is the same as saying ordered() on your stream. Because of that, it makes sense why it grabbed Optional[1].
By the way, I told you that once you use parallel(), you CANNOT get EXECUTION ORDER. If you want EXECUTION ORDER, you should use a non-parallel stream, also known as a sequential stream. Sequential means you only do 1 at a time. THAT will give you EXECUTION ORDER. That is why the result for this one is as you expected -- because Stream.of() is a SEQUENTIAL stream. So, you get EXECUTION ORDER. But as a result, you lose parallelism.
YOU CANNOT HAVE EXECUTION ORDER AND PARALLELISM TOGETHER. If you want that, build your own solution or do something non-standard.

What do you think parallel does?
The map operation on the stream elements are all run in parallel. The fact that the job is identical does not mean that they all take precisely equally long. One thread does not have to run on the same efficiency core. Or one gets interrupted and the other does not, and so on. Hence, once thing run in parallel, order disappears.
You don't get your Optional[1] back 'first' because all 4 run in parallel. Java is not a time machine; it cannot, once it realizes the '1' is a workable answer, go back and retroactively change time so that the other 3 never started.
You might be thinking: Well, the first (remember, there is no 'first', not when we are talking parallel(), but hypothetically) will pass, because we're just asking for any result. But the stream API doesn't know that. Maybe you intend to run a filter on whatever comes out of map, and that's the whole point of parallel: Run all 4 map ops simultaneously, then apply filtering to all 4 simultaneously. Whatever one survives - take whatever one ends up at the finish line (the .findFirst()) first and return it.
Why does it return an Optional? For the same reason. What if all 4 end up not passing a filter? Then no elements remain. The fact that you don't have a filter is immaterial. There could be one. The API is written with that in mind. Attempt to craft a type system that can represent both 'the stream operation is guaranteed to return at least one result' and 'the stream operation may not return any results' and see how far you get. (you won't get very far).

Yes, I understand that the mapping operation will happen in parallel. But I am asking about the final result. That should be ordered for an ordered stream, right? I am getting that it is not possible to determine the order of the objects generated in the outgoing stream of an intermediate operation.
Secondly, if I insert an unordered() operation before parallel(), the result is still Optional[1]. Why? Why does it wait for mapping operation of 1 to complete when others have already completed? findFirst on an unordered stream should be able to return any element, right?

Adding unordered() marks the stream pipeline as unordered. It doesn't have to re-shuffle to change the order of elements. Also it doesn't wait for the mapping operation of 1 to get complete. What you are seeing is a result of parallel operations. Try with more number of elements and you can confirm there will be elements left unprocessed (i.e., not reach the map stage)

@Priyshrm Order preserved at the terminal operation, not on intermediate operations: If a 'parallel but ordered' stream also orders the intermediates, it wouldn't be parallel! Hence why peek (which is an intermediate operation) does not show order. You are seeing shortcutting behaviour. Stick enough stuff in that stream and it won't peek all the elements. But, with 4 in the stream, all 4 have 'started' (and got as far as peek) before findFirst() went: Y'all can call it a day, I have an answer.
